# DataGrid WPF Fields

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, field, cell

I have a datagrid with 3 DataGridTextColumns

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn   Header="Field Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="BeginFields"  Header="Begin" Binding="{Binding Begin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="LengthFields"  Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

All three DataGridTextColumns data gets added into an ObservableCollection.
I iterate through the collection to get an instance, and set the values for the next row.

The program needs to Update accordingly if any of the fields get updated.

Right now I can only manipulate the Beginning field, but not the Length Field.

Think of the beginning field as a line in the text document, and the length field as the next line in a text document, these two fields must be perfectly apart and never overlap each other, I hope I made sense in what I am trying to accomplish I am fairly new to programming and my algorithm skills are not potent. Please assist me , If something I said does not make sense please let me know I will elaborate as best as I can. 
See Code for more details.

Thank you!!

[The DataGrid View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XeG3.png)

I will now past the Code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = MWVM.FieldsCollection;

    fileButton.Click += FileButton_Click;
    loadPresetButton.Click += LoadPresetButton_Click;
    savePresetButton.Click += SavePresetButton_Click;
    clipboardButton.Click += ClipboardButton_Click;
    saveButton.Click += SaveButton_Click;

    ****dataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged += ((o, e) =>
    {
        int track = 0;

        foreach (Field f in MWVM.FieldsCollection)
        {
            track += f.Length;


            f.Begin = track - f.Length;
        }
    }); ****
}
```

---

```
public class Field : ViewModelsBase
{

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");

        }

    }
    private int _begin;

    public int Begin
    {
        get
        {
            return _begin;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _begin)
            {
                _begin = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Begin");
            }

        }
    }


    private int _length;
    public int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _length)
            {
                _length = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Length");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Blank { get; set; } = "";
}
```

---

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelsBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Field> fieldsCollection;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _fields = CreateFieldsCollection();
    }



    private ObservableCollection<Field> CreateFieldsCollection()
    {
        fieldsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Field>();
        return fieldsCollection;  
    }

    ObservableCollection<Field> _fields;

    public ObservableCollection<Field> FieldsCollection
    {
        get

        {
            return _fields;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_fields != value)
            {
                _fields = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FieldsCollection"); 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this logic in your view model class.

You could handle the `PropertyChanged` event of each `Field` object that is added to the `ObservableCollection<Field>` and recalculate the Begin and Length fields accordingly. Please refer to the following sample code which should give you the idea:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelsBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _fields = CreateFieldsCollection();
        _fields.CollectionChanged += _fields_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Field> CreateFieldsCollection()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Field> fieldsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Field>();
        fieldsCollection.Add(new Field() { Begin = 0, Length = 5 });
        fieldsCollection.Add(new Field() { Begin = 5, Length = 5 });
        fieldsCollection.Add(new Field() { Begin = 10, Length = 5 });
        fieldsCollection.Add(new Field() { Begin = 15, Length = 5 });
        fieldsCollection.Add(new Field() { Begin = 20, Length = 5 });
        foreach (Field field in fieldsCollection)
            field.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
        return fieldsCollection;
    }

    private void _fields_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object field in e.NewItems)
            {
                (field as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object country in e.OldItems)
            {
                (country as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

    }

    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_fields.Count < 2)
            return;

        switch(e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Length":
                //recalculate the begin of each field
                RecalculateBegin();
                break;
            case "Begin":
                Field modifiedField = sender as Field;
                int indexOfModifiedField = FieldsCollection.IndexOf(modifiedField);
                if(indexOfModifiedField > 0)
                {
                    //recalculate the length of the previous field:
                    Field previousField = FieldsCollection[indexOfModifiedField - 1];
                    previousField.Length = modifiedField.Begin - previousField.Begin;
                }
                //...and the recalculate the begin of the rest of the fields:
                RecalculateBegin();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RecalculateBegin()
    {
        int length = _fields[0].Begin + _fields[0].Length;
        for (int i = 1; i < FieldsCollection.Count; ++i)
        {
            FieldsCollection[i].Begin = length;
            length += FieldsCollection[i].Length;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Field> _fields;
    public ObservableCollection<Field> FieldsCollection
    {
        get { return _fields; }
        set
        {
            if (_fields != value)
            {
                _fields = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FieldsCollection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Friend, amazing you figured out what Ive been trying to accomplish for what feels like eons... the algorithm is definitely it, but please forgive me, the screen shot I uploaded  has misled you ..the DataGrid will always start  with 1 row and empty fields , the user will populate the cells/fields as they go, there is no preset values in the cells like the picture Ive uploaded...  the application starts, there will only be 1 row and the DataGrid will generate additional rows based on the users need. Again thank you! and sorry for the horrible explanation.

Comment: You should see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of the answer. Click on it to accept the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Cheers, to you my friend!